# Unable to connect to gihub on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github

I am unable to connect to github on Jenkins

Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://github.com/av/automation.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/pass5555555555555555555.sh': Text file busy
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Comment: Check if your server that is hosting Jenkins is not running out of disk space...